# What's the definition of Goldstone Mode?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

My question is how to define a Goldstone Mode?

Initially I thought that Goldstone Mode is a consequence of spontaneous symmetry breaking, but later I learned that  in Kosterlitz–Thouless transition, the spontaneous symmetry breaking is absent but we still have Goldstone Mode there.

To make it more self contained,the reason for the absence of spontaneous symmetry breaking in Kosterlitz–Thouless transition is Mermin Wagner's theorem, which states that continuous symmetries cannot be spontaneously broken at finite temperature in systems with sufficiently short-range interactions in dimensions d ≤ 2(this is copied directly from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem).The goldstone mode in 2d classical XY model is the direction of spin on each site,/theta, which can be regarded as spin wave.

So I'm wondering how should we define a Goldstone Mode?

Is this definition work?

Def: 
Any low energy long wavelength mode is Goldstone Mode.

Comment: Please a) consider to spell out acronyms (e.g. I can certainly guess what the "KT transition" is but it's better for readers in general to not have to guess) b) try to make the post somewhat self-contained, e.g. by adding an explanation what you understand to be the Goldstone boson in KT and why you think there is no symmetry breaking there.